# Aggregate pub/sub messages

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using Cloud Pub/Sub to push notification payloads generated by events done throughout the day. I have another cloud function triggered by schedulers at the end of the day to pull notifications from pub/sub and send email notifications.

I want to have the feature of aggregated notifications for users. So I want to merge all the payloads generated for a specific user to be grouped by user and send a notification.

I have thought to make a separate subscription for each user, and then I will process all messages from a subscription as aggregated payloads. But this doesn't seem like a good solution.

Is there any way to merge pub/sub messages based on a key or attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no operation in PubSub to achieve that. You must perform a post process. There are 2 options according to the volume of data

1. Volume is low: You can pull all the messages and store them in the memory of your Cloud Functions, sort the messages per user, and then send the notification. Set the PubSub timeout to 9 minutes to have the time to perform all your processes before acknowledging the messages
2. Volume is too high (or you want a scalable solution): Store the message in a database, in real time it's better than in bulk. Then perform your query and send your notification. Finally clear the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the events with information of users in mongoDB or redis and can run a cron job at the end of the day to club the data and send the notification to the user. Remove the data after it has been used.

Comment: I'm expecting a huge amount of messages, so I wanted to avoid DB reads. Also, I'm already pushing all messages to one topic as other functions are utilizing data from there. So if I have data to pub/sub already I want to avoid read/writes on DB.